# Конвертирование JSON строки в class с __slots__

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Запрашиваю данные по апи от какого либо сервиса, при помощи библиотеки requests, ответ получаю в формате JSON

```
{
  ...
  "data": [{
    "title":"Blabla",
    "price": 1234,
    ... 
  }]
  ...
}
```

Ответ достаточно большой, и преобразование строки в словарь методом response.json() весит в памяти более 500 Мбайт. Если объекты в массиве data завернуть в классы с **slots**

```
class Model:
  __slots__ = ('title', 'price',)
  def __init__(self, title, price):
    self.title = title
    self.price = price
```

то объем данным в памяти становится порядка 3 Мбайт.

Сейчас есть промежуточное преобразование в dict (response.json()) и потом уже dict в класс c **slots**, что создает скачок по памяти.

Подскажите есть ли какое либо готовое решение которое позволит преобразовывать строку напрямую в класс с **slots** ?

Comment: А можно чисто из академического интереса узнать, зачем вы хотите запихнуть эти данные в класс?

Comment: Может быть имеет смысл посмотреть в сторону pandas? Он вроде бы умеет читать напрямую из json, и данные в памяти хранит достаточно компактно.

Comment: @strawdog как написал при распаковке json в dict, ответ занимает очень большой объем памяти, если те же объекты завернуть в класс, то потребляемая память в сотни раз меньше

Comment: @Xander про pandas думал, но мне кажется это слишком для данной задачи

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте решение через [object_hook](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads):

```
import json

class Model:
    __slots__ = ('title', 'price',)
    def __init__(self, title, price):
        self.title = title
        self.price = price

def hook_Model(dct):
    if 'title' in dct and 'price' in dct:
        return Model(dct['title'], dct['price'])
    return dct

json_text = """
{
  "data": [{
    "title":"Blabla",
    "price": 1234 
  }]
}
"""

data = json.loads(json_text, object_hook=hook_Model)
print(data)
# {'data': [<__main__.Model object at 0x000001C422B022E8>]}
```

Comment: мне почему-то кажется, что у автора как раз самая большая проблема с объявлением __slots__ в классе, нежели чем с присвоением значений.

Comment: @strawdog, а мне кажется, ему не нравится конвертирование из словаря в свой класс :)